# How to clear the cache for Common Lisp?

Tags: caching, common-lisp

I am using Common Lisp, SBCL, and Slime to load a system that is a web browser. The system used to work properly until a few days ago.

Now, I am still able to successfully load the system. Also, I am able to start the program. I can even use the browser to navigate on internal documents, such as the manual.
However, the application freezes when I try to load web pages.

After reading possible solutions to fix this problem, one of them suggests *"clearing my cache for common lisp"*.

I have already re-started emacs or even the PC. But the problem persists.

How am I supposed to clear my cache for Common Lisp?

Comment: in your home directory there is a .cache/common-lisp directory with cached compilation results, you can remove the contents so that everything is build anew (next time you restart the application  this will take longer). If that does not work you may want to contact directly the developers, they are more likely to understand the problem (Nyxt browser?)

Comment: exactly, @coredump. Nyxt browser! I am one of the developers haha. But I am still a noob and I did not want to bother colleagues with this question. Thanks!

Comment: "but doctor I am Pagliacci"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to try the comma-command in the REPL: `,delete-system-fasls` RET system name, aka `slime-delete-system-fasls (name)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find `slime-delete-system-fasls (name)` maybe I'm using an old slime version.
On REPL `(asdf:load-system system :force t)` worked for me on a case,  which was not Nyxt, though.